# Python Logging: Provide log file path from main module

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

Is there any way I can provide the **filename** for logger from my main module?

I am using following way, however it's not working.all the logs go to **xyz.log** file rather than **main.log**

**Updated as per suggestion from nosklo**

**logger.py**

```
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='[%(asctime)s] - {%(filename)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


def _get_file_handler(file_name="xyz.log"):
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(file_name)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    return file_handler


def get_logger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(_get_file_handler())
    return logger
```

**parser.py**

```
log = logger.get_logger(__name__)


def parse():
    log.info("is there anyway this could go to main.log and xyz.log")
```

**main.py**

```
log = logger.get_logger(__name__)
if __name__ == '__main__':

    for handler in log.handlers:
        if isinstance(handler, logging.FileHandler):
            log.removeHandler(handler)
            log.addHandler(logger._get_file_handler())

    log.info("is there anyway this could go to main.log and xyz.log?")
    parser.parse()
```

Is there a way I can set the **Log file name** from my `main.py` module and not from `logger.py` module?

Answer (score 2):

Logging instances can have multiple file handlers.  Use a function like this to just add another handler with the additional output path you want.  Log messages will get sent to both (or all) text logs added to the instance. You can even configure the handlers to have different logging levels so you can filter messages to different logs for critical errors, info message, etc.

```
import logging
def add_handler(output_log_path, log):
    # Set up text logger and add it to logging instance
    file_logger = logging.FileHandler(output_log_path)
    file_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | logger name: %(name)s | module: %(module)s | lineno: %(lineno)d | %(message)s')
    file_logger.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(file_logger)
    return log
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `get_logger()` first, so when you set the class attribute in `FileName.file_name = "main.log"` the `get_logger` function is already finished, and the logger is already defined to write in `xyz.log`; Changing the variable later won't change the logger anymore, since it is already defined.

To change the previously selected file, you'd have to retrieve the logger, remove the previous handler and add a new file handler. Another option is to set the variable **before** calling `get_logger()` so when you call it, the variable already has the correct value.

Comment: now I am changing the file name in handler from main module, now also it's not working. will have to remove to handler and add again:

Comment: @GaurangShah update the code to reflect your new approach, so we can see what you're trying.

Comment: `__name__` is a dynamic variable that returns the name o f the current module, so, `logging.getLogger(__name__)` creates a logger based on the name of the module. If you want to modify parser.py logger from main.py maybe you want to use `logger.get_logger('parser')`