# Python colored logging in custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I wanted to add some logging to colored print statements.
The naive approach was to create a function

```
def log_and_print(msg,level='info',color="", reset=""):
    if level == 'info':
        logging.info(msg)
    elif level == 'debug':
        logging.debug(msg)
    print(color+str(msg)+reset)
```

It works fine, but discovered that of course the path that is being logged isn't correct anymore. Is there some better solution? I hoped to be able to keep the log_and_print function, since it is used in a lot of places.

Comment: Look about https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich

Comment: What is the expected path and what is the path you're getting?

Comment: @Datajack I believe the source of the log message would be from a different file/module instead of where the function `log_and_print` is called from

Comment: @shoaib30 exactly. So maybe the suggestion with rich is the right approach. In that case, I would have to rewrite of course all the calls of the log_and_print function.

Comment: @MichaelRazum I don't know about logging, but does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37546770/python-choose-logging-files-directory) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824566/python-logging-provide-log-file-path-from-main-module) help you? The second one seems similar to what you want, I think...

Comment: Not entirely sure of what you are trying to achieve with the print statement, but have you tried implementing a custom log handler that will print the way you want and call the default handler for the rest. that way you don't need to call `log_and_print` you can just use the logger

Comment: @shoaib30 a call would look this way
`log_and_print("log_str",color=Fore.CYAN)`
with `from colorama import Fore`. Before that it was just  print(Fore.CYAN + "log_str"). 
When print was exchanged with `logging.info(Fore.CYAN + "log_str")` it added ugly artifacts in the log message.

Comment: Got it, it would help if you add that to your question. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56944256/5236575) out. You can create two handlers and attach formatting and output of one log to the console and the other which you already have. It would work if your colors are tied with the log levels

Comment: @MichaelRazum another option - https://github.com/Delgan/loguru#pretty-logging-with-colors

Comment: It does not answer your specific question of maintaining the path when logging from a function, hence I am not adding these as an answer.

Comment: @shoaib30 thanks a lot! Guess will try logging-with-colors and shib. The color is not tied to the log level. Another solution would be maybe somehow to read out the path of the parent function and add it as an additional parameter to logging as kwargs. But seems a bit ugly as a workaround.